# Is it possible to connect IBM DevOps services with my RQM?

Tags: ibm-cloud, rtc, rational-team-concert, requirements-management

I want to use my Rational Quality Manager (RQM) in connection with a project I've created on IBM DevOps services with the Track&Change feature enabled. Is it possible to set up cross-server communication between the hosted RTC and Rational Quality Manager?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a supported integration. I've passed your message on to DevOps Services' development team, however.